# Method to get these JSON entries

Tags: javascript, json

I am working in javascript with JSON payloads like below, and I am curious about the best way to get all entries of each element. For example, how could I get all entries of "o4" in some order (-159, -257)?

```
{
  data: {
    '1613152800': {
      i0: -264,
      i1: 297,
      i2: -260,
      i3: 270,
      i4: -159,
      i5: 0,
      i6: -7,
      i7: 145
    },
    '1613153400': {
      i0: 261,
      i1: -239,
      i2: 125,
      i3: -214,
      i4: -257,
      i5: 3,
      i6: -237,
      i7: -128
    }
  }
}
```

This example has two main entries '1613152800' and '1613153400', but in reality there will be hundreds of those.

**I won't know the main entry id's before hand either**, so the '1613152800' and '1613153400' will always be unknown. I can't rely on

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json.data['1613152800'].i4);
```

for example.

Thanks!

Comment: `json.data.values().map(({i4}) => i4);`

Comment: Did you try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?

Comment: would this be what you are looking for? Object.values(). from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 3):

You can take `Object.values` and `map` it:

```js
const obj={ data: { '1613152800': { i0: -264, i1: 297, i2: -260, i3: 270, i4: -159, i5: 0, i6: -7, i7: 145 }, '1613153400': { i0: 261, i1: -239, i2: 125, i3: -214, i4: -257, i5: 3, i6: -237, i7: -128 } }}

const getEntries=(obj, key)=> Object.values(obj.data).map(({[key]:v})=>v);

console.log(getEntries(obj,'i4'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the properties in your `data` object:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
var ids = [];
for(var id in json.data) {
  ids.push(id);
}
```

Now you have an array of the "id" objects. You can access the objects by their indices:

```
console.log(ids[0].i4);
```